# Authentication in microservices (different options, pros and cons)

Tags: authentication, microservices

I want to understand pron and cons of different implementation of single sign-on authentication and authorization in microservice environment. I came up with 3 solutions (see the diagram below).
What pron and cons does each option have? (I'm using Ocelot as gateway and IdentityServer4 as identity provider). Microservice A and Microservice B have it's own UI (SPA applications), Microservice D is REST API.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain my point of view:

**Option 1**:

I understand that first of all you have to be logged against an identity server using user credentials and then create the cookie. I wouldn't recommend this option, first because as I can see you don't validate the cookie and it contains the userId that it is propagated to the servers, so the user could change the userId to get information about other users. And second, because this approach makes you to have a cookie policy

**Option 3**:

As I can see, in this option you are doing the login on each application. So, if in the future you have other applications you will have to implement the login page and logic in each of them.

**Option 2**:

I think it is the best of them, but I would make a change. First of all, it is a good option to have an api gateway that take care of cross concerns like authentication/authorization talking to the identity server to request acces tokens and to try to call the services. Doing this you will have a unique login point and the gateway could check the permissions (scopes) to do the actions required by the user, so the services wouldn't have to take care of this. The only thing I would change is the validation in each of the services. Because the nature of JWT tokens, it will contains all info needed to validate itself (expiration time, issuer, audience.. etc) so this validation won't be necessary. And to avoid the possibility of manipulation, the best approach is to sign the token by trusted certificate and let the gateway check the integrity, so when the token reach the services you have the confidence that this is a valid user with proper rights to do the action